# Return the unique values of a specific column line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have the following `dataframe`

```
  column1 column2  
0 Paul       xx       
1 John       aa      
2 Paul       gg      
3 John       xx       
4 John       bb       
5 George     gg       
6 Paul       gg
7 john       xx
.
n Jonathan   ff
```

I want to have the information of each person in one row. On the same `row` I want to have the `index` but in another `column`. So I want a `dataframe` like this:

```
  column1     column2   column3  
 0 Paul        0,2,6     xx, gg, gg       
 1 John        1,3,4,7   aa, xx, bb, xx             
 5 George      5         gg       
 .
 .
 .
 n Jonathan    n         ff
```

In order to make the above `dataframe` i execute

```
df2 = df.reset_index().groupby('column1').agg(list).reset_index()
ix = pd.Index(df2['index'].str.get(0)).rename(None)
df3 = df2.set_index(ix).sort_index()
df3
```

Which returns:

```
      column1      index          column2
0        Paul     [0, 2, 6]      [xx, gg, gg]
1        John     [1, 3, 4, 7]   [aa, xx, bb,xx]
5      George        [5]             [gg]
```

After that, I delete `column1` and `index`.
To have the values of `column2` in a format, not represented as `list` I execute:

```
def transform_list(df3):
    df3['column2'] = df3['column2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
    return df3

dfb=transform_list(df3)

df3.head()
```

which return:

```
    column2
0   xx, gg, gg
1   aa, xx, bb,xx
5   gg
```

So now what I want is to have the unique values of each `row`

so my final `dataframe` will be

```
  column2
0   xx, gg
1   aa, xx, bb
5   gg
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `','.join(set(x))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the order of the elements in your output doesn't matter, you can redefine your function as follows:

```
def transform_list(df3):
    df3['column2'] = df3['column2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))
    return df3
```

A set contains inherently only unique elements, so converting the list `x` to a set will discard any duplicates.  Sets are inherently unordered however, so you may get unintended results if order matters.

If order does matter, you can use the version

```
def transform_list(df3):
    df3['column2'] = df3['column2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(list(dict.fromkeys(x))))
    return df3
```

This creates a dictionary (which is insertion ordered) with keys from your initial list `x`, and since the keys can't be multiply defined, we end up with only the unique elements.  Converting back to a list takes the keys from the dictionary, and the rest of the workflow can continue as needed without alteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform each list to a set and then back to a list, to eliminate duplicate entries. This could be done within your lambda function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column2': [['xx', 'gg', 'gg'],
                               ['aa', 'xx', 'bb', 'xx'],
                               ['gg']]},
                  index=[0, 1, 5])

df['column2'] = df.column2.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(set(x))))
df
```

```
    column2
0   gg, xx
1   bb, xx, aa
5   gg
```